# Writting query using CDbcriteria for CgridView in YII.?

Tags: php, yii, query-builder, yii-components

I am trying to show my data in `gridview` and in process have written the following query which I am trying to write using `CDBCriteria`,

```
//query

SELECT user. * , jobs. * , COUNT( jobs.user_id ) 
FROM user
INNER JOIN jobs ON user.id = jobs.user_id
GROUP BY user.id
```

I have tried the following thing:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select ='user.*,jobs.*';
$criteria->select ='COUNT(jobs.user_id)';
$criteria->select ='user';
$criteria->join   ='INNER JOIN jobs ON user.id = jobs.user_id';
$criteria->group  ='user.id';

return new CActiveDataProvider('manageemployers', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
```

my view have the following code.

```
 <?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
     'dataProvider' =>$model->search(),
     //   'filter' => $model,
     'columns' => array(
         array(
             'name' => ' Employer ID',
             'type' => 'raw',
             'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->id)',
             'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;','class'=>'zzz'),
             // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */

         [...]

?>
```

My contoller

```
public function actionManageEmployers() {

    $user_id = Yii::app()->session['user_id'];
    if (Yii::app()->user->getId() === null)
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    $model = new ManageEmployers();
    $model->user_id = $user_id;


    $this->render('manageemployers', array('model' => $model, 
    ));
}
```

But its not working. Please help me on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

So now I'm able to understand your problem and I tried to fix it with this.

i think i had the solution, you don't need to get the data in the `search()` like you did it. you can use relations and other stuff to get your data.

firstly i would add a relation to your user-model like this:

```
'jobs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Jobs', 'user_id')
```

after that, you can access all jobs of the user with `$model->jobs`

then you **need to undo your changes** of the `search()`-function. I mean that it must look like this:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('attribute',$this->attribute);
    //this is just an example ^

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

changes in the **action**:

```
$model = new ManageEmployers();
```

to this:

```
$model = new ManageEmployers("search");
```

changes in the **view**:

add something like this to your `colums` array:

```
array( 
    'name' => 'Total Jobs Posted',  
    'value' => 'count($data->jobs)', 
    'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;','class'=>'zzz'), 
)
```

Comment: and what about rest of statements...have to write as it is.?

Comment: @saji, I think the rest should work. Or did you get an error? if yes, please tell me which error you get.

Comment: @Dinistro.getting error  "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'user'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT user.*, jobs.*, COUNT(jobs.user_id) as alias, user FROM `user` `t` INNER JOIN jobs ON user.id = jobs.user_id GROUP BY user.id) sq"

Comment: @saji, this error is, because you do not have a table `user`, how is the table called?

Comment: @saji, are you sure? PHP says no ;-) Are you sure, that you are connected with the right database?

Comment: ya I am sure...   in model  public function tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51579/discussion-between-dinistro-and-saji)

Answer (score 0):

If you have table relations set up, then in your User model (that refers to your user table) try writing your `CDbCriteria` like so:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('jobs' => array('joinType' => 'STRAIGHT_JOIN'));
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->addCondition('id = jobs.user_id');

return new CActiveDataProvider('manageemployers', array(
  'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

Comment: and where is the count?